# How do I crash web crawlers that do not obey my robots.txt file?

Tags: web-services, server, web-crawler

What data should I send to the bad web crawlers so that I can crash them?

Answer (score 1):

Better strategy is to create a blacklist. Many malicious crawlers look for "standard" URLs. For example, I don't run PHP websites, so I know if someone requests a PHP file from me, they're phishing. So I block them: immediately and unconditionally.

Use services of www.projecthoneypot.org, which help you recognize "suspicious" crawlers: You can then decide to let them proceed or block them.

If you really want, you could send them massive files rather than block them, but remember: they're bots & have all the patience in the world.